# Why is Bamboo not logging any Ant build output?

Tags: java, ant, continuous-integration, bamboo

I'm trying to get a very old project's Ant build to run on an Atlassian Bamboo server.  The server is set up on the same VM as several other Atlassian applications, which I'm aware is a Bad Idea, but am unable to solve at the moment.

My main issue is that running an ant build through the Bamboo interface results in this error-

> Failing task since return code of [C:/apache-ant-1.10.1\bin\ant.bat -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Atlassian\Bamboo\temp\AN-AN-JOB1 -f build.xml run] was 1 while expected 0

I'm not getting any more Ant error output in Bamboo than this, which seems strange.  I've run Node scripts and gotten output from `Console.log()`, so it's certainly possible in this setup.  If anyone does get error output for Ant builds in Bamboo, just that information would be much appreciated.

When I copypasta the command Bamboo is running into a terminal and run it from the top level of my project, I get the message:

> BUILD FAILED
>       Target "C:\Atlassian\Bamboo\temp\AN-AN-JOB1" does not exist in the project "HelloAnt".

Removing the line `-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Atlassian\Bamboo\temp\AN-AN-JOB1` makes it build just fine, which makes it seem as though `"C:\Atlassian\Bamboo\temp\P2N-AN-JOB1"` is somehow being passed to ant as a build target instead of setting the `java.io.tmpdir` system variable as I suspect it is supposed to.

Bamboo is pretty stubbornly refusing not to put the offending line in there.  I've been able to edit the path that it references through Bamboo's config files, but that hasn't proven terribly helpful.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long story short, the executable ant.bat had been encrypted to my account by Windows, so when I ran Ant builds with my local user they worked fine, but Bamboo was unable to even start Ant.

I discovered this while trying to run Ant through a powershell script in the Bamboo interface.  I'm guessing that Bamboo runs Ant using cmd.exe by default, since running an ant build using that provided the same obtuse `1 while expected 0` output, while running powershell gave the much more helpful message `Program 'ant.bat' failed to execute: Access is denied`.